# About bitwise data

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am not sure if it relates to "bitwise". I store a music file provided with different format. eg. MP3, WAV, midi... It needs to store the provided type in the DB. One of the solution is to create individual db fields/columns for each format. eg withMP3, withWav, withMidi... But once I add one more format, I need to create an extra column.

Is there any standard solution to store the format to one field? For example first digit store with mp3, second digit store with wav... Once I add one more file format, it just needs to append one more bit to the data, no need to add new column. I am not sure this question related to any aspect. Hope that someone can help me.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Turn that data into its own table (id, format, blob) then you can associate them with the rows in the other table via another table. That way the schema is independent of the number of formats.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you try to store this information as fields. I would just store the mime type, that is normally enough information for a normal database.